# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock?

Tags: linux, docker, service

$sudo service docker start

```
* Starting Docker: docker
```

$sudo service docker status

```
* Docker is not running
```

$sudo docker pull bkimminich/juice-shop

```
  Using default tag: latest
   Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect 
   to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon 
   running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
   Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the 
   docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Can you add output off `sudo systemctl status docker.service` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to: https://www.santoshsrinivas.com/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04/

- Add the group `docker` (**skip if exists**).
- Then, add the `user` to the group `docker`.
- Finally, restart the service.

## Also, you need to logout and login (user) again after you added the groups.

```
bash
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
sudo service docker restart`
```